# Rails calling the class itself with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layer

I am writing some wrapper to an external service Layer. I would like to create some helpers like `Layer::CreateIdentity(uid)` and `Layer::UpdateIdentity(uid)`. In which I will use layer-api gem and do some logic inside.

I will put these helpers in `lib/layer/create_identity.rb` etc.

When designing the class, I don't want to do something like `Layer::CreateIdentity.new(uid).call`. Rather I just want to do `Layer::CreateIdentity(uid)`.

Is there ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is a class method rather than an instance method.

```
class Layer
  def self.CreateIdentity(uid)
    uid
  end
end

2.2.2 > Layer::CreateIdentity(1)
=> 1
```